# Does changing Magento SKU affect the Order History

Tags: magento

I have a request to change the SKU for an existing product, so I am wondering if changing the SKU will affect the order history of this product. Since SKU is a global Identifier in Magento I am not sure what would be the effect of changing it. This is Magento 1.7 CE

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Order data is stored in the sales_flat_order_item and sales_flat_order tables.  If you change the SKU of a product in your catalog, it will not affect the SKU of the product on already existing orders.

[image: sales_flat_order_item]

Regards,

Comment: After changing SKU my previous order not open, how can i open my order? magento ver : 1.9.2.3 Comm.Edi

Answer (score 0):

Changing the SKU of an active product, and or the flat product's afterword will NOT retroactively update the sales order history.

100% sure on this.

Sales Order History
Referencing the old SKU to the "New" Sku will result in some broken behavior that must be accounted for, this especially is true in Configurable products.

Cheers,
-J

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/2_-_magento_concepts_and_architecture/catalog_database_tables